# Skype Max OSX Main.db file no history on local machine

Tags: macos, mac, skype

I want Skype to store my conversations in the cloud so when I login using different PC's I can see history.

**I Don't want skype to record history on my local hard drive is this possible only to cloud ?**

The preferences privacy tab shows that I can choose length of time to keep conversations it does not mention is this for cloud or local drive.

ty

Comment: Skype conversation are stored in the cloud, so the setting, configures your settings for the cloud.  Your local client simply caches your conversation history.

Comment: "I Don't want Skype to record history on my local hard drive is this possible only to cloud ?" - The current version of the Skype client doesn't offer an option to disable this.